# Hacking a Corsair Commander Pro

Tags: transistors, hacking

I unfortunately shot two Transistors of my Commander Pro because I drew to much current when I connected a pump to the fan-connector.
Now I want to desolder these two transistors, but I can't figure out the exact part number. The only markings are a "Y2" on top of the transistor (see picture). I couldn't find where the transistor is connected to ground. I also couldn't find a circuit diagram anywhere.

How can I find out which type (pnp or npn) it is?
Can I hack it anyway so that I can connect a pump to the port in the future, like buying a beefier transistor?

PS: I wrote an e-mail to corsairs support, but have little hope.

[image: said transistor]

Comment: Should we all know what a Corsair Commander Pro is? I don't!  You're looking for a part number rather than a serial number.

Comment: You want a transistor in a SOT23 package. Most likely a NPN bipolar type, maybe a N-channel enrichment MOSFET. Go to e.g. the Mouser website for such transistors and check each of the ~300 datasheets for the Y2 marking. If you are lazy, try a BC847.

Comment: The pins seem obvious. Bottom is probably the source through that jumper 0 ohm resistor and diode and beefy pad. The top left looks to be the output also to a beefy pad. The top right is likely the gate or base since its a small trace. Have you used a multimeter to trace out to pads with the continuity tester?

Comment: Based on a forum post its a pnp transistor with the top left as the emitter to vcc and the bottom as a collector to the load. They used a MMSS8550 as a random replacement.

Comment: I researched some more and Corsair obviously didn't give out the exact part number, so can I damage anything other than the transistor by choosing the wrong type?

Answer (score 0):

A pump is undefined for the load current. But for a beefy driver use a low RdsOn logic level FET.

The SMD code for Y2 could be the PNP transistor SS8550 so a Pch would be compatible and for 2A and worst-case power dissipation of 200mW from I^2Ron=Pd.  Choose smaller Ron ($) or external FET for bigger currents with a suitable heatsink.  Chose Imax rating 10x what you need to achieve low Ron.